# Underscan only one side

Tags: macbook-pro, display

This is a weird one.. I have a portable second monitor I use to work when on the road, but I use a clip to secure it to my MacBook (https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07ST3VXLG/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_image_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) but this then eats into my screen slightly on the two contact points. I can just resize all windows when I move them across but would be awesome to have some sort of auto resize or somehow resize the screen, I know I can just add some underscan but that then removes all sides of the screen, not just one.

TIA

Comment: Not weird at all. There’s software to do precisely what you seek